# When I hover over the menu item, i want to display the line at bottom? What is wrong with my code?

Tags: html, css, hover

When i hover over menu item it displays the line (border) at bottom, but the problem is that it pushes down the border of the `ul`, i want that when i hover over menu item it displays the **border-bottom** on that ul line, so it wouldnt push it down... How can i fix this? *(Sorry, becouse of my english, if it isnt understandable)*

Here is my ***HTML*** & ***CSS***:

```css
.menu-section-wrapp {
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-section {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.menu li {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}
.menu li:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
a {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 12%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Roboto";
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-section-wrapp">
  <div class="menu-section">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">FAQ</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Hire us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method to solve this is
write

```
.menu li {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.menu li:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to give the menu a transparent bottom border when it's not being hovered so that the hover doesn't make a jump when the border is added

```
.menu li {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```css
.menu-section-wrapp {
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-section {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.menu li {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.menu li:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
a {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 12%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Roboto";
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-section-wrapp">
  <div class="menu-section">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">FAQ</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Hire us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple

```
.menu li:hover {
      margin-bottom:-1px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

just append

> margin-bottom:-1px;